# How to calculate the upper and lower sum of a definite integral using the darboux definition

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I have no idea how to calculate the L(f,P) and U(f,P) for this question. Can anybody please help me out?

$f(x) = -x, x\in[0,1];P=\text{{0,$\frac{1}{8}$,$\frac{1}{3}$,0.9,1}}$

Comment: The terms of lower sum are the infima (minimum in this case) of $f$ on the interval multiplied by the length of the interval. For example, on $[0, 1/8]$ you’d get $1/8(-1/8)$

Comment: So it'd be negative 1 in this case?

Comment: I'm still kinda confused.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say $P=\{x_0, x_1 ,...,x_n\}$ then $$L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i (x_i-x_{i-1})$$
Where $m_i$ is the infimum of $f$ on the interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ (Which is like the minimum value). For example in your case $m_1 = -1/8$ since that is the minimum value of $f$ on $[0,1/8]$. So your first term in the sum will be $-1/8 \cdot 1/8$, since $1/8$ is the length of the first interval. Do this for the other intervals and add them all.

For the upper sum you do the same thing but use the supremum (maximum) of $f$ on the sub intervals.

Comment: so it'd be $\frac{-1}{64}$ plus the min for all the other intervals?

Comment: @deezythe next term will be $(1/3-1/8)\cdot -1/3. You have to multiply the min for each interval by the length of that interval

Comment: And for the max we just multiply by the max of that interval?

Comment: @deezy  That is correct.

Comment: Would the same rules apply if f(x) was a constant?